# Is there a faster way to load an ImageTK Object while also taking less memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So, I'm developing a Tkinter application using Python 3.9.7 in the newest version of Spyder.

TL;DR -> Jump to the end of this question and read the "My questions are:", although in order to properly understand them, it is necessary to understand how I'm currently opening my images and displaying them as ImageTk objects.

> from tkinter import * 
>  from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
>  import pickle

In order to display images on my tkinter canvases, I make use of the following method:

1. All of my images are stored as _io.BytesIO Archives inside several pickle DAT archives.
2. Those _io.BytesIO objects are opened using Image.open(b_obj) # b_obj is the _io.BytesIO Object.
3. After the conversion into PIL images through the 2nd step, all images are stored in a **single python dictionary**, called "anidict". The keys of anidict are named in a standardized faction, accordingly to the screen that the images are supposed to be disposed.

    > Example: anidict['PIL_mainscreen_background'] leads to a list gathering the PIL images related to the background animation of the mainscreen.
4. Finally, all PIL images are converted into Tkinter Images using the ImageTk.PhotoImage method, then stored inside a temporary dictionary, and finally stored inside anidict, now with keys that are standardized with "ImageTK" prefix. 
    > anidict['PIL_mainscreen_background'] will still exist, but now anidict['ImageTK_mainscreen_background'] will also be a key of anidict, leading to the collection of ImageTKs related to the background of the mainscreen.

In order for the animations to show properly, I have a single thread that is always active until the finalization of the program. This thread is composed of a function with several if-elif statements, each checking global boolean variables that change accordingly to which screen the user is seeing by the moment.

```
def image_update_thread():
    if is_seeing_mainscreen:
        # Update of a single frame of the mainscreen background animation
        canvas_mainscreen.itemconfigure(ms_image, image= anidict['ImageTK_mainscreen_background'][next_image_index]) #ms_image is the image object of this particular canvas, which is constantly itemconfigured. It has been defined previously as ms_image = canvas_mainscreen.create_image(x_position, y_position, image= anidict['ImageTK_mainscreen_background'][0], anchor='nw')
    elif is_seeing_screen2:
        # Update a single frame from another animation
    ...
    ...
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    image_update_thread() # Calls this function again and again, until termination.
```

The problem I'm facing is: as the application grows in size, the amount of images that I'm using also increases, and is currently at ~800 individual images being opened and converted to ImageTks. This is causing the memory usage to go wildly up (as far as taking ~2.200MB of RAM), while also increasing the time needed for the application to initiate (note: I've set the application so it only opens after all images load).

My questions are: is there a faster way to do these same processes? How can I deal with the increased memory usage?

Note: I've considered using spritesheets to reduce the amount of individual images being loaded, but eventually, as the application grows, the amount of images tends to reach the same point again, so I'm seeking for a way to improve the coding, and not how the artwork is delivered.

Comment: How many images will be on the screen at any one time? It sounds like you should just load the images when you need them rather than all at once, but will only work if you're just showing a few at a time rather than thousands at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the rep! Most of the application loads only one animation at a time, but I have one particular section that needs to update 12-18 different animations concomitantly... With that said, it gets pretty time consuming to convert 18 PILs into TKImages per 0.1 second in that specific section... I could try applying your suggestion at the singular animation sections, but that would still leave the heavier ones unattended.

Comment: I doubt anybody can help without a complete [mcve]. I just did an experiment loading 10 small images from disk and to took less than 2ms.  It seems that the first thing you should do is only try loading the images you need for the current page, rather than trying to load them all at once.

Comment: I will code your suggestion and test it out to see if it works for me. In case it does, I will let you know. If it still takes too much time or memory, then I will edit this question and add the MRE. Regardless of the result, thanks for the replies and ideas! =)